# Center text on two lines inside a div

Tags: css

I'm having some trouble centering a text inside a div. The text, "Project description" is a little bit longer than the other options so it is displayed on two lines.

Here's the code responsible for this:

```
.left-menu {
    float: left;
    width: 109px;
    margin-right: 33px;

}

.left-menu .button {
    width: 108px;
    height: 64px;   
    background-color: #E6E6E6;  
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

.left-menu .button a {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 64px;
    color: #00359F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5z2qwo6/1/).

How can I make the word "description" to be displayed right bellow the word "Project"?

Thank you!

Comment: Decrease the `line-height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle to match what you want.
All you'll have to do is still adjust the `line-height` property on the `.left-menu .button a` to match the exact spacing you want, I've set it to `30px` to make it look 'alright' for now.

The way this works is by using tables, make the `.left-menu .button` `display: table;` and it's child `.left-menu .button a` `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: middle;` and it will center multiple lines vertically.

Your CSS will look like this

```
.left-menu .button {
    width: 108px;
    height: 64px;   
    background-color: #E6E6E6;  
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table; // make the display table here.
}

.left-menu .button a {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px; // adjusted line-height so that multiple lines fit in one menu.
    color: #00359F;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table-cell; // child has to be table-cell
    vertical-align: middle; // this vertically centers the text
}
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/SidOfc/L5z2qwo6/2/)
css tricks article on the subject [here](https://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)

Comment: @Cosmin if it helped you out and solved your problem, mark it as accepted so that other people that find this will be able to view this as the accepted answer ;) furthermore no problem at all!

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. Done!

Answer (score 2):

Update these rules in your CSS file:

```
.left-menu .button {
    width: 108px;   
    background-color: #E6E6E6;  
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-menu .button a {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00359F;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I've changed the line height on the `a` and removed the fixed height on the button too as it's better to achieve what you're after with padding. See this link for a working version https://jsfiddle.net/sukky4r3/2/

Comment: Yes, but now the "Project description" button is bigger than the other buttons. The buttons must have the same height.

Comment: Well it will be, you're adding 2 lines where the others are 1. This is more scalable than using fixed heights